# Difference between setting a fetch size on Statement vs ResultSet

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, resultset

What is the difference between setting a fetch size on Statement vs ResultSet? Oracle documentation says that if fetch size is set on a Statement then the same is used by ResultSet as well, as long as the fetch size is set prior to obtaining the result set. What difference does it make if I set it on Statement or a ResultSet? I am using Oracle database. Following is Oracle documentation about it:

> Fetch Size
>
> By default, when Oracle JDBC runs a query, it retrieves a result set of 10 rows at a time from the database cursor. This is the default Oracle row fetch size value. You can change the number of rows retrieved with each trip to the database cursor by changing the row fetch size value.
>
> Standard JDBC also enables you to specify the number of rows fetched with each database round-trip for a query, and this number is referred to as the fetch size. In Oracle JDBC, the row-prefetch value is used as the default fetch size in a statement object. Setting the fetch size overrides the row-prefetch setting and affects subsequent queries run through that statement object.
>
> Fetch size is also used in a result set. When the statement object run a query, the fetch size of the statement object is passed to the result set object produced by the query. However, you can also set the fetch size in the result set object to override the statement fetch size that was passed to it.

Answer (score 5):

The only place the fetch size really matters is on the `ResultSet`. When a `ResultSet` is created, it gets its fetch size from the `Statement` that was used to create it, but it can be changed later.

Think of the `Statement`'s fetch size as a default that will be passed to all the `ResultSet`s it creates. If you don't want to use this default, you can override it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference. If you set the fetch size on the statement then it will apply to all ResultSet instances that come from this statement.

Comment: There is a slight difference. The fetch size set on the statement will be used for the first fetch. By the time the result set is returned the first fetch is complete so the only way to control the size of the first fetch is to set it on the statement. If you know a particular query returns only one row then setting the fetch size to 1 on the result set will do nothing as the statement's fetch size will already have been used to retrieve the one row before your code has access to the result set to set the fetch size to one.